# Why does the client keep getting stuck on the read method in the client?

Tags: java, networking

I have created 2 Java applications to form a chat room, and the client application freezes when trying to read a message over the network.

It never says 'leaving readText', but it does say 'Inside readText' on the client application.

Server Application:

Server.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Server
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        final int PORT                  = 2525;
        Socket sock                     = null;
        ServerSocket serverSocket           = null;


        UserHandler userHandler             = null;

        try
        {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket( PORT );
            System.out.println( "Service started..." );
        }
        catch( IOException exc )
        {
            System.out.println( "Failed to start service..." );
            System.exit( 0 );
        }

        do
        {
            sock = hSSocket.accept();
            System.out.println( "Incoming connection..." );
            userHandler = new UserHandler( sock );
            userHandler.start();
        }while( true );

    }

}
```

UserHandler.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class UserHandler extends Thread
{
    private Socket  sock                    = null;
    private Scanner in              = null;

    private String user                 = "";
    private boolean loggedIn                = false;

    public UserHandler( Socket sock ) throws IOException
    {
        super("UserHandler");
        this.sock = sock;

        in = new Scanner( this.sock.getInputStream() );
    }

    public void run()
    {
        String inText;

        System.out.printf( "Running...\n" );

        do
        {
            inText = in.nextLine();
            System.out.println( msg );

            try
            {
                processInText( inText );
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }while( !msg.equals("Disconnect") );

        try
        {
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void processInText( String inText )
    {
        String password = "";

        code = msg.substring( 0, 4 );

        switch( inText )
        {
        case "User":

            if( loggedIn )
            {
                System.out.println( "Already logged in" );
                sendText( "allw" );
                return;
            }

            if( inText.length() > 5 )
            {
                name = inText.substring( 5 );
                System.out.println( "Asking for password" );
                sendText( "Pass" );
                return;
            }

            sendText( "allw" );

            break;

        case "Pass":

            System.out.printf( "password received %s\n", inText.substring(5) );

                    if( user.equals( "user" ) && inText.substring( 5 ).equals( "pass" ) )
                       loggedIn = true;

                    break;

        default:
            System.out.println( "Unknown" );

        }
    }


    private void sendText( String outText )
    {
        PrintWriter out = null;
        System.out.println( "Inside sendText" );
        try
        {
            out = new PrintWriter( sock.getOutputStream() );

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println( "Sending message..." );
        System.out.printf( "%s\n", outText);
        out.println( outText );
        System.out.println( "Message sent..." );
    }





}
```

Client Application:

Client.java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Client extends Thread
{
    private static final int PORT           = 2525;

    private Socket sock                 = null;
    private InetAddress host                = null;
    private Scanner in              = null;
    private PrintWriter out         = null;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setup();
        client.start();
    }

    public void sendText( String outText )
    {
        out.println( outText );
    }

    public String readText()
    {
        String inText = "";
        System.out.println( "Inside readText" );

        if( in != null )
            inText = in.nextLine();

        System.out.println( "leaving readText" );
        return inText;
    }

    public void setup()
    {
        try
        {
            host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            sock = new Socket( host, PORT );
        }
        catch( IOException exc )
        {

        }

        try
        {
            in = new Scanner( sock.getInputStream() );
            out = new PrintWriter( sock.getOutputStream(), true );

        } catch (Exception e)
        {

        }

    }


    private void sortText( String inText )
    {
        try
        {

            System.out.println( "Handling comms..." );

            switch( inText.substring( 0, 3 ) )
            {
                    case "User":
                System.out.println( "Sending user" );
                sendText("User user" );
                break;

            case "Pass":
                System.out.println( "Sending pass" );
                sendText("Pass pass" );
                break;

            case "Disc":
                System.out.println( "User " + msg.substring(3) + " disconnected." );
                break;

            case "allw":
                System.out.println( "logged in" );
                break;

            default:

                System.out.println( "Who knows what the server is saying" );
            }
        }
        catch( Exception e)
        {

        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        String inText = "";

        do
        {
            System.out.println( "sending user" );
            sendText( "User user" );
            System.out.println( "User sent" );
            readText();
            System.out.println( "sending pass" );
            sendMessage( "Pass pass" );
            System.out.println( "Pass sent" );

            inText = readMessage();
            sortText( inText );

        }while( !inText.equals( "Disconnect" ) );



    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the sendText() method of Client?

Comment: it's the sendMessage method... I renamed a few things at the same time as posting.

Comment: You need to start by not ignoring exceptions. Anything could be happening.

Comment: I ignored them all, because my output is GUI based, but I've placed them back in and there's no output from any of the exceptions... The flow of the communication seems to be working as the server side is outputting everything after each message it receives, but the client side just gets stuck when trying to read.

Comment: I believe I may have solved the issue with using out.flush(); Please wait out though as I have other errors to contend with and once I've fixed those, then I will confirm whether this was the correct solution or not.